# Wordpress Elementor: Expand/Collapse on hover on accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am using wordpress with the elementor add on. Though it provides very sleak accordion which works perfectly on click, I wanted to expand/collapse the accordion on hover. Used the below JQuery which works but not as clean as the click as it is using CSS so there is no animation/slow loading of the accordion. Pretty new to JS but can someone help me to replicate the "animation/slow loading" as happens on click of the accordion element?

Working JQuery which does not expand/collapse nicely:

```
(function($){

  $('.elementor-tab-title').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("elementor-active", 10000 );
     $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').addClass("elementor-active", 10000 );
     $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').css({"display": "block"});
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("elementor-active", 10000 );
    $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').removeClass("elementor-active",10000 );
    $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').css({"display": "none"});
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML that this works with and the relevant CSS that styles it, in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I understand what you are looking but it would make it much easier for us to help if we have an example to work with and show you the result.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    
    $(".elementor-tab-content").fadeOut(0);
     $(".elementor-tab-title").hover(function() {
          $(".elementor-tab-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
          $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
     });
    
});
```

Or another, this one expands on mouse over and can only be collapsed with a click

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
     $('.elementor-tab-title').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("elementor-active", 10000 );
     $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').addClass("elementor-active", 10000 );
     $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').stop().slideDown("fast");

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem. this works fine for me.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.elementor-tab-title').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("elementor-active");
    $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').slideDown(400); // Adjust the animation duration as needed (e.g., 400 milliseconds)
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("elementor-active");
    $(this).parent().find('.elementor-tab-content').slideUp(400); // Adjust the animation duration as needed (e.g., 400 milliseconds)
  });
});
</script>
```